# matplotlib: How to get colors (or facecolor) from histogram bars?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, axes, getcolor

I have a histogram using a list as a datasource and I want to get the colors, or facecolor of each of the bars in order to diagnose a problem.

`patches.facecolor()` isn't working for me.

```
#The histogram
n, bins, patches = ax.hist([lst_outliers, lst_standard], num_bins, rwidth=0.8, color=['red','blue'])

#This is how I'm trying to access the facecolor attribute of ax.patches:
patches[0][21].get_facecolor()

#It yields the following for all bars; I can't tell if this is some kind of color code:
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

#Ultimately, I would like to build on the following to diagnose another problem (some day soon I will write list comps): 

for i, each_bin in enumerate(bins):
    print(str(i+1) + " " + str(each_bin))
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get the color that you set yourself. What would be the purpose of that? (Note that (1,0,0,1) is just the RGB value of red)

Comment: The purpose is to build a diagnostic function/loop.
I need to verify that bars are being assigned the right color, so I want to get the color after it has been assigned.